# String matching in URL using Hive / Spark SQL

Tags: regex, string, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables, one containing list of URL and other having a list of words. My requirement is to filter out the URLs containing the words. 
For eg:

```
URL

https://www.techhive.com/article/3409153/65-inch-oled-4k-tv-from-lg-at-a-1300-dollar-discount.html
https://www.techradar.com/in/news/lg-c9-oled-65-inch-4ktv-price-drop
https://www.t3.com/news/cheap-oled-tv-deals-currys-august
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/gadgets/lg-bets-big-on-oled-tvs-in-india-to-roll-out-rollable-tv-by-year-end-5823635/
https://www.sony.co.in/electronics/televisions/a1-series
https://www.amazon.in/Sony-138-8-inches-Bravia-KD-55A8F/dp/B07BWKVBYW
https://www.91mobiles.com/list-of-tvs/sony-oled-tv

Words

Sony
Samsung
Deal
Bravia
```

Now I want to filter any URL that has any of the words. Normally i would do a

```
Select url from url_table where url not like '%Sony%' or url not like '%Samsung%' or url not like '%Deal%' or not like '%Bravia%';
```

But that's a cumbersome and not scalable way to do it. What is the best way to achieve this? How do I use a not like function to the words table?

Comment: Please check my answer, using words table

Comment: Thanks @leftjoin. I will try it out and let u know soon :) thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex:

```
 where url not rlike '(?i)Sony|Samsung|Deal|Bravia'
```

`(?i)` means case insesitive.

And now let's build the same regexp from the table with words.

You can aggregate list of words from the table and pass it to the rlike. See this example:

```
with 

initial_data as (--replace with your table
select stack(7,
'https://www.techhive.com/article/3409153/65-inch-oled-4k-tv-from-lg-at-a-1300-dollar-discount.html',
'https://www.techradar.com/in/news/lg-c9-oled-65-inch-4ktv-price-drop',
'https://www.t3.com/news/cheap-oled-tv-deals-currys-august',
'https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/gadgets/lg-bets-big-on-oled-tvs-in-india-to-roll-out-rollable-tv-by-year-end-5823635/',
'https://www.sony.co.in/electronics/televisions/a1-series',
'https://www.amazon.in/Sony-138-8-inches-Bravia-KD-55A8F/dp/B07BWKVBYW',
'https://www.91mobiles.com/list-of-tvs/sony-oled-tv'
) as url ) ,


words as (-- replace with your words table
select stack (4, 'Sony','Samsung','Deal','Bravia') as word
),

sub as (--aggregate list of words for rlike
select concat('''','(?i)',concat_ws('|',collect_set(word)),'''') words_regex from words
)

select s.url
  from initial_data s cross join sub  --cross join with words_regex 
  where url not rlike sub.words_regex --rlike works fine
```

Result:

```
OK
url
https://www.techhive.com/article/3409153/65-inch-oled-4k-tv-from-lg-at-a-1300-dollar-discount.html
https://www.techradar.com/in/news/lg-c9-oled-65-inch-4ktv-price-drop
https://indianexpress.com/article/technology/gadgets/lg-bets-big-on-oled-tvs-in-india-to-roll-out-rollable-tv-by-year-end-5823635/
Time taken: 10.145 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

Also you can calculate sub subquery separately and pass it's result as a variable instead of cross join in my example. Hope you got the idea.

Comment: why we are using cross join ? Since sub contains only a single row, cant we use normal join also?

Comment: @BitanshuDas You can calculate variable separately. It is example. Use any join you want. The question was not about join. And cross join w single row in hive will work as mapjoin. also normal join wiothout ON condition is the same cross join.

Comment: hey @leftjoin, how scalable is this? Is there any more optimized way of doing this if the data size is in TBs?

Comment: If the list of words is too big and does not fit in single regexp then it will be a problem definitely.

Comment: @BitanshuDas Another possible solution is to split URL using '[-/.]' as a regex delimiter (you will get array of words in url), then explode array and left join with words table. Exploding array wil produce too many rows. and will work slow.

Comment: @BitanshuDas One more possible solution is to split url and not explode. Join with words table (cross) and use array_contains(word). This will produce main table x words rows. Also not the best solution.

Comment: @BitanshuDas In both solutions you will need tricky filtering to filter out whole url if one word matched. analytic function or simple aggregation will do. like max(matched_flag) group by url+ filtering on it. IMHO if the list of words fits into single regexp, then the best solution is using rlike. If not, then try some other solution.